# Binding a Specific Context to a Function: Why does my "Hack" work?

Tags: javascript

In Secrets of JavaScript Ninja Listing 5.7(pg 100), the assertion fails:

```
<body>
  <button id="test">Click Me!</button>

<script>
 var button = {
     clicked = false;
     click: function(){
         this.clicked = true;
         assert(button.clicked, "The button has been clicked");
     }
 };

 var elem = document.getElementById("test");
 elem.addEventListener("click", button.click, false);
</script
```

The author's solution was binding the context to an event handler in the Listing 5.8. However, I found editing the click function in the following ways worked.

```
 click: function(){
     button.clicked = true;
     assert(button.clicked, "The button has been clicked");
 }

 click: function(){
     this.clicked = true;
     assert(this.clicked, "The button has been clicked");
 }
```

I don't understand why it works, an answer to this that expands my JavaScript knowledge would be appreciated.

Comment: `assert(this==button, "oops")`

Comment: tl;dr: it works because in both cases you are accessing the same object when writing and reading the `clicked` property. `button === button` and `this === this`, but `button !== this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `button.clicked` works because `button` refers to your object so you can set and check the `.clicked` property.

Your final example using `this.clicked` only *seems* to work in that it lets the `assert()` pass but doesn't actually set the `.clicked` property of your `button` object because `this` is not equal to `button`. It's actually setting and then testing a `.clicked` property on `window` because without binding the context `this` will (for the code shown) refer to `window`.

If the book you are reading doesn't explain `this` in a way that you can understand then perhaps the [MDN article on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) will help instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the elusive nature of `this`. Example:

```
function someFunction(){
     //In this context "this" refers to the window object, so you're setting 
     //clicked = true on window, not button!
     this.clicked = true;         
}
```

To address your examples that work:

```
click: function(){
     button.clicked = true;
     assert(button.clicked, "The button has been clicked");
 }
```

The above works because you're reerencing the button variable directly, through button.clicked. This works nicely. There can be no misunderstanding. It's like saying "Hey John!" in room full of people, instead of saying "Hey you!" and hoping the right person responds.

```
 click: function(){
     this.clicked = true;
     assert(this.clicked, "The button has been clicked");
 }
```

Here the above works, because you are using this in the same context. this refers to the function, so here the clicked variable is actually being set on `window`. But because you're also referencing the same `this` in your assert, it works.

The rule of thumb is that `this` references the *current object*. If you're making a call that's not inside an object, you are in the context of the global scope, and `this` refernces the window object. This I learned today. Thanks guys!

Edit: Corrected error, per nnnnnn's comment.

Comment: `this` will not refer to the function itself, it will be `window`.

Comment: _"this refers to the function"_ - No it doesn't. The fact that you've now given the function a name doesn't change the fact that `this` will not refer to the function itself, it will still be `window`. The value of `this` has nothing to do with whether a function is anonymous.

Comment: *"I try to avoid much use of `this`"* a bad advice IMO. That can quickly lead to tightly coupled code that is difficult to reuse. Better learn how `this` works, it's not that complicated, and 99% of the time you are in full control of what `this` refers to.

Comment: It wasn't meant as an advice, per se, more of a personal preference. You're right in that it's best to learn the different aspects of `this`!

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys.  It helped :)